# JS: change "var y = UNDEFINED" for "var y= blank space" with if

Tags: javascript, undefined, innerhtml, var

I have a table generated from a textarea filled by users, but some of the time, a cell stays empty (and that's all right).

The thing is that the `.innerHTML` of that cell is also my `var y` in a script and when that cell is empty (therefore, undefined), my `var y` becomes UNDEFINED too (the value, not a string), which makes my whole script fail.

Here's a snippet to show the problem:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body><center>

</center></body>

<!--------- script that generates my table from text areas -->
<script>         
    function generateTable() {
                    $('#excel_table1').html("");
      var n=1;
      var rows=[];
      var lng=0;
      var maxligne=0;
                     
     $('textarea').each(function(){
       var data = $(this).val();
                        if (data !=''){
       var rowData = data.split("\n");
       rows[n] = rowData;
       lng = rowData.length;
                    if(lng > maxligne)
                    {
                     maxligne=lng   
                    }
                      n++;  
                
                    }
                    }
    
    )
     var table = $('<table />');
     k=0;
     while (k < maxligne) {
      var row = $('<tr />');
      for(var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++)
      {
       var singleRow = rows[i];
                            
                            if(singleRow[k]!= undefined){
       row.append('<td>'+singleRow[k]+'</td>')  
      } else {
                        row.append('<td></td>') 
                            }
                        }
      table.append(row);
      k++;
     }
     $('#excel_table1').append(table);
    }    
   </script>
      
      <textarea placeholder="data 2 Here" name="data1" style="width:100px;height:40px;"></textarea> 
        
  <textarea placeholder="data 2 Here" name="data2" style="width:200px;height:40px;"></textarea>
        
  <textarea placeholder="fild not required" name="data3" style="width:200px;height:40px;"></textarea>
   
   <br>
            
   <input id=bouton1 type="button" onclick="javascript:generateTable()" value="GenerateTable"/>
      
      <div id="excel_table1"></div>
      
<!--------- script that get the data from cells to show it in <H2> -->

<script type="text/javascript">

     function buttonTEST()
               {
                $('#displayCell').html("");
                   
                var x = document.getElementById('excel_table1').getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].cells[1].innerHTML;
                var y = document.getElementById('excel_table1').getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].cells[2].innerHTML;
               if (y === undefined) {
    y = " ";
}
                   
             document.getElementById('displayCell').innerHTML = x +" "+ y;
             }
              
 </script>
 
 <br/><br/>
       <h2 id="displayCell"></h2>
 <br/><br/>
      <input id="Button2" type="button" onclick="buttonTEST()" value="TEST ME"/>
```

As you can see, if you generate a table with only to columns (which is supposed/needs to happen sometimes), we get this error from the console because we're trying to get "innerHTML" from a undefined:

`index.html:120 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined`

A little specification: When that cell is=`undefined` , I need it to stay `undefined`, I only want to change the fact that my `var y` also becomes undefined.
So I thought that changing the value of `var y` (and not the value of that cell, otherwise, the 3rd column, supposed to be empty, would be created just because of an blank space) to a blank space would resolve the problem, but I don't seem to get it right (write it in a correct manner).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: Your script is not failing because y is undefined. It's failing because you're trying to get the innerHTML of an element that is undefined. Either one of the cells or the "reponse" element.

Comment: You seem to have jQuery, yet resort to good old native DOM functions. Save for blatant coding errors, you possibly wouldn't have problems with undefined elements if you just stuck to the library.

Comment: @palaѕн Yes, good idea. It's way easier to understand now, thanks!

Comment: @JonasHøgh Yes you're absolutely right! But I actually already know that, but I can't remove `innerHTML` from `getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].cells[2].innerHTML`, because when the cell exists, I need the `innerHTLM`of it; That's why I'm trying to change the value of my `var` when `undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the answer that worked for me:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body><center>

</center></body>

<!--------- script that generates my table from text areas -->
<script>         
    function generateTable() {
                    $('#excel_table1').html("");
      var n=1;
      var rows=[];
      var lng=0;
      var maxligne=0;
                     
     $('textarea').each(function(){
       var data = $(this).val();
                        if (data !=''){
       var rowData = data.split("\n");
       rows[n] = rowData;
       lng = rowData.length;
                    if(lng > maxligne)
                    {
                     maxligne=lng   
                    }
                      n++;  
                
                    }
                    }
    
    )
     var table = $('<table />');
     k=0;
     while (k < maxligne) {
      var row = $('<tr />');
      for(var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++)
      {
       var singleRow = rows[i];
                            
                            if(singleRow[k]!= undefined){
       row.append('<td>'+singleRow[k]+'</td>')  
      } else {
                        row.append('<td></td>') 
                            }
                        }
      table.append(row);
      k++;
     }
     $('#excel_table1').append(table);
    }    
   </script>
      
      <textarea placeholder="data 2 Here" name="data1" style="width:100px;height:40px;"></textarea> 
        
  <textarea placeholder="data 2 Here" name="data2" style="width:200px;height:40px;"></textarea>
        
  <textarea placeholder="fild not required" name="data3" style="width:200px;height:40px;"></textarea>
   
   <br>
            
   <input id=bouton1 type="button" onclick="javascript:generateTable()" value="GenerateTable"/>
      
      <div id="excel_table1"></div>
      
<!--------- script that get the data from cells to show it in <H2> -->

<script type="text/javascript">

     function buttonTEST()
               {
                $('#displayCell').html("");
                   
var x = $('#excel_table1 tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)').html();
var y = $('#excel_table1 tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3)').html();
               
 if (y ===undefined)

    {document.getElementById('displayCell').innerHTML = x ;}
               
 else
     {document.getElementById('displayCell').innerHTML = x +" "+ y;}

    }
              
 </script>
 
 <br/><br/>
       <h2 id="displayCell"></h2>
 <br/><br/>
      <input id="Button2" type="button" onclick="buttonTEST()" value="TEST ME"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var x = document.getElementById('excel_table1').rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML;
var y = document.getElementById('excel_table1').rows[0].cells[1].innerHTML;
```

using rows instead of `getElementsByTagName` is cleaner.
Also note that the indexes for cells start from zero not 1, you probably only have 2 cells in your first row, but `.cells[2].innerHTML` tries to get the innerHTML of the 3rd cell which does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I know that the cells count starts at zero, that's not the problem. The thing is that the table number of columns (therefore n° of cells) changes. I made a snippet in my question. Hope it's clearer  now!

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you're already using jQuery, so the easiest way to get the cell contents is to use a css selector to find the cells using the `$` function, then call `.html()` to get the contents. A direct conversion of your current code to this approach could be:

```
var x = $('#excel_table1 tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)').html();
var y = $('#excel_table1 tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3)').html();
```

This works in a way so that the `$` function returns a jQuery object, which is essentially a set of elements, which can potentially be empty. Most jQuery functions are then designed to fail gracefully when called on an empty set. For instance, `html` will return undefined when invoked on an empty set, but it will not fail.

Note that it is not very robust to use the selector above, as it is obviously sensitive to the placement of the cells. It would be more maintainable to assign a class attribute to the cells that describes their content, and then select on that, e.g. something like

```
var name = $("#excel_table1 tr:nth-child(1) td.name").html()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, `$` function was the answer indeed. From that, I just had to add an if `(y ===undefined)` then just show `var x`  `else` show `var x` and `var y`